# how to make the drupal t function not case sensitive in drupal 7 in php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, localization, drupal-7

hi I am having some problems with the Drupal t or Drupal.t('') for JavaScript function, is it possible to make the t function not case sensitive in Drupal
example: if I do this

```
echo t('ABC');
```

or

```
echo t('abc');
```

can I make them both give the same result; for English the result would be

```
ABC
```

or

```
abc
```

and for other languages both will give only on result, example:

```
ابت
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'ABC' and 'abc' are different strings for t().I dont think its possible through t() , maybe you should prepare your strings with PHP formatting/casing before inserting to t()

Here are the [string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) you need